# How to restore contacts in android 6

Tags: contacts, nexus-5, restore, 6.0-marshmallow

Today I flash android 6 on my nexus 5. It is really not ready to use the system. I have many problems. For example, all my SMS have been deleted. It is OK. But I lost my contacts too. How to restore them?

Of course, I logged into my account. Of course, I have WIFI. Usually, contacts restore from Cloud backup, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

Contact means your Phone contact or gmail contact ?? Well if you are asking for gmail contact then go to your gmail account and check out your contacts are visible or not ? Go to this link - - http://www.google.com/contacts , if the contacts are there then you can easily access that on your phone via google sync.

Try this software - ->  Android Data Recovery

1) Download the software from the below link, install the software in your PC

2) Connect your Mobile with PC .

3) Turn on USB Debugging by going to - -> Settings - -> Application --> Development- -> USB Debugging.

4) When your Phone get connect with PC, you have to press Start button to start the scan, it will take 20-30 min to scan.

5) When scan get complete, you will see your contacts and other options like SMS on the  left pane. Select the relevant option that you want to restore and Press - -> Restore.

6) Disconnect your phone and check out your contacts in the phone.

**Taken Reference:**

http://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/recover-deleted-contacts-from-samsung-galaxy-s4.html

Answer (score -1):

Same happened to me. It helped when i opened recent calls tab in dialer and loaded full recent history. It managed to get most of the lost numbers from there or anyways it helped. Worth of trying.